# Prototype function replacing the original object

Tags: javascript, function, prototype

I am trying to a prototype which will have a function

```
Function.prototype.abc = function () {
    this = function () {console.log("test")}
}
```

for example.

and then when I define a function and call `func.abc();` I want it to replace the function.
but it just says

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
```

at the `this = x` line.

How do i go about doing this?

Comment: `this` is a keyword and can't be used as a variable name.

Comment: > *I want it to replace the function* What? Something wrong with `func = ...`?

Comment: If you wanted to *shadow* that function for the current object only, then `this.abc = func() {...`. Other than that, I can't really tell what you want.

Comment: ...if you wanted to replace the function on which `abc()` was invoked, you can't. That would require pointers, and JS doesn't have them. Closest would be to return a function and have the caller overwrite. `my_func = my_func.abc()`

Comment: Then ill just have to
    `Function.prototype.abc = function () {
        return function () {...}
    }
    lorem = lorem.abc();`